# Blurred Image as background in UIView

Tags: ios, swift

So I have an image that I am rendering in a view. For the background color of that uiview I actually want a `UIImage`. The way I was doing was taking the currentImageView and applying this function `makeBlurEffect`.

```
  func makeBlurImage(targetImageView:UIImageView?)
    {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = targetImageView!.bounds

        blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] // for supporting device rotation
        targetImageView?.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    }
```

I typically set the background image and apply the blur filter inside the lazy var method that creates the `UIView` as shown below.

```
lazy var blurryBackGround : UIView = {
    let blurryBackGround = UIView()
    blurryBackGround.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    // blurryBackGround.backgroundColor = UIColor(i)
    var blurryImage = currentImageView
    blurryImage.makeBlurImage(blurryImage?)
    return blurryBackGround
}()
```

I have also included the `UIImageView` creation:

```
//
lazy var currentEventImage : UIImageView = {
    let currentEvent = UIImageView()
    currentEvent.clipsToBounds = true
    currentEvent.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    currentEvent.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    currentEvent.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    currentEvent.layer.masksToBounds = true
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePromoVid))
    currentEvent.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    currentEvent.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    return currentEvent
}()
```

Any idea how i would correctly do this?
The current way I implemented would blur the original image, change the blurred image to the main image and turning the background image to the unblurred image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following extension:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func renderedImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

To capture currently presented `imageView` to an `UIImage`.

**EDIT**

How about you try not capturing it yet, just use this as a background:

```
lazy var blurryBackGround : UIView = {
    let blurryBackGround = currentImageView
    blurryBackGround.makeBlurImage(blurryBackGround)
    return blurryBackGround
}()
```

Comment: @RonBaker this should make a screenshot of what is rendered through the `UIImageView`.. so since you are adding the blur effect to the imageView, I believe it should work as you expect. Just try it, and you'll see

Comment: well actually i want to add a blur effect to the image in the imageview and make it the background of my UIView, this will accomplish that?

Comment: im sorry if im not getting it or confusing you

Comment: @RonBaker I'm not sure if the code you have written above was correct, but try something I added in the updated answer

Comment: sorry if im wrong or critiquing but your code seems to return an imageView and not a UIView would that even work?

Comment: `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`, so `UIImageView` can be used everywhere where `UIView` can be used.. as per the question "would that even work?" - why don't you try it?

Comment: sorry just asking bro but this is what happened 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163888/discussion-between-milan-nosa-and-ron-baker).